# Simple rails app on Puma throws segfault, cannot handle concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, segmentation-fault, puma

I have a fairly simple Rails app. It listens for requests in the form

```
example.com/items?access_key=my_secret_key
```

My application controller looks at the secret key to determine which user is making the call, looks up their database credentials, and connects to the appropriate database to get that person's items.

However we need to have this support multiple requests at a time, and Puma seems like everyone's favorite / the fastest server for us to use. We started running into problems when benchmarking it with ApacheBench. FYI, puma is configured to have 3 workers and min=1, max=16 threads.

If I were to run

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 127.0.0.1:3000/items?access_key=my_key
```

then this error is thrown with a whole lot of stack trace after it:

```
/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
```

**Edit:** This line also appears in the enormous amount of info that the error contains:

```
*** glibc detected *** puma: cluster worker 1: 17088: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007fb671ddbd60
```

And it looks to me like that's tripping multiple times. I have been unable to determine exactly when (on which requests) it trips.
The benchmarking seems to still finish, but it seems quite slow (from ab):

```
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   21.085 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Total transferred:      3620724 bytes
```

21 seconds for 3 megabytes? Even if mysql was being slow, that's... bad. But I think it's worse than that - the amount of data isn't high enough. There are no segfaults when I run concurrency 1, and the amount of data for -n 10 -c 1 is 17 megabytes. So puma is responding with some error page that I can't see - running 'curl address' gives me the expected data, and I can't manually do concurrency.

It gets worse when I run more requests or higher concurrency.

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 127.0.0.1:3000/items?access_key=my_key
```

yields

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 199 requests completed
```

and

```
ab -n 100 -c 50 127.0.0.1:3000/items?access_key=my_key
```

yields

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 6 requests completed
```

Running `top` in another putty window shows me that very often (most times I try to benchmark) only one of the three workers puma created is performing any work. Rarely, all three do.

Because it seems like the error might be somewhere in here, I'll show you my application_controller. It's short, but the bulk of the application (which, like I said, is fairly simple).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def get_yaml_params
    YAML.load(File.read("#{APP_ROOT}/config/ecommerce_config.yml"))
  end

  def access_key_login
    access_key = params[:access_key]

    unless access_key
      show_error("missing access_key parameter")
      return false
    end

    access_info = get_yaml_params

    unless client_login = access_info[access_key]
      show_error("invalid access_key")
      return false
    end

    status = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql2",
      :host     => client_login["host"],
      :username => client_login["username"],
      :password => client_login["password"],
      :database => client_login["database"]
    )
  end

  def generate_json (columns, footer)
    // config/application.rb includes the line 
    // require 'json'
    query = "select"
    columns.each do |column, name|
      query += " #{column}"
      query += " AS #{name}" unless column == name
      query += ","
    end
    query = query[0..-2] # trim ','

    query += " #{footer}"

    dbh = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

    results = dbh.select_all(query).to_hash

    data = results.map do |result|
      columns.map {|column, name| result[name]}
    end

    ({"fields" => columns.values, "values" => data}).to_json
  end 

  def show_error(msg)
    render(:text => "Error: #{msg}\n")
    nil
  end
end
```

And an example of a controller that uses it

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    access_key_login or return

    columns = {
      "prd_type" => "prd_type",
      "prd_type_description"   => "description"
    }

    footer = "from cin_desc;"
    json = generate_json(columns, footer) 
    render(:json => json)
  end
end
```

That's pretty much it as far as custom code goes. I can't find anything making this not threadsafe, so I don't know what the cause of the segfaults is. I don't know why not all of the workers spin up when requests are made. I don't know what error is getting returned to ApacheBench. Thanks for helping, I can post more information as you need it.

Comment: Is your Rails database pool large enough?  Look in config/database.yml

Comment: @GrahamSavage I'm not certain. It's set to 5 right now - is that the maximum number of concurrent mysql connections?  I will test that at a higher number. Also, do you know how high it can go?

Comment: @GrahamSavage Increasing it to 5000 (with -n 10 -c 5) still segfaulted. I noticed another line in the huge backtrace that might be helpful for working out the error though. See edit.

Comment: A segfault means either a bug in Ruby or a C extension. Try upgrading both to the latest patchlevel available. 2.0.0 is on p594 right now.

Comment: I second @ChrisHeald - but I would go further and say upgrade to Ruby 2.1.3 if nothing in your app depends on the older Ruby.  I've had all manner of issues with Ruby 2.0 and various dependencies - the latest of which was openssl after upgrading to Yosemite.

Comment: Apologies, I had started in 2.1.4 before and it was the same error. A supervisor instructed me to try 2.0.0, and it never got changed back. I'm moving to 2.1.3 now, will update.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Upgrading to 2.1.3 didn't fix the segfault - I'm thinking there is a problem with my mysql2 libraries as per the error message. I'm going to try reinstalling some stuff

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the stable version of mysql2 library, 0.3.17, is NOT threadsafe. Until it is updated to be threadsafe, using it with multithreaded puma will be impossible. An alternative would be to use Unicorn.